# How to get Spark Streaming latency and throughput performance metrics?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm interested in benchmark of Spark application. The Spark application is a streaming application in particulatr. The following performance metrics are needed:

- Latency of spark job
- Throughput: # records processed per second
- Write latency to HDFS storage

For **Latency**, I am not sure what would be ideal metric for a streaming application? Maybe the latency in processing X GB of data?

I am looking at eventLog and I see events that look as follows:

`27 {"Event":"SparkListenerTaskEnd","Stage ID":0,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Type":"ShuffleMapTask","Task End Reason":{"Reason":"Success"},"Task Info":{"Task ID":0,"Index":0,"Attempt":0,"Launch Time":1519875848448,"Executor ID":"2","Host":"wn4-spark.qnzkwaodrnqefgaghyn41qkb1a.xx.internal.cloudapp.net","Locality":"RACK_LOCAL","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":1519875850052,"Failed":false,"Killed":false,"Accumulables":[{"ID":1,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorDeserializeTime","Update":494,"Value":2143,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":2,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorDeserializeCpuTime","Update":51432980,"Value":414880553,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":3,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorRunTime","Update":1022,"Value":5065,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":4,"Name":"internal.metrics.executorCpuTime","Update":133512654,"Value":650061315,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":5,"Name":"internal.metrics.resultSize","Update":2004,"Value":10812,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":6,"Name":"internal.metrics.jvmGCTime","Update":95,"Value":427,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":8,"Name":"internal.metrics.memoryBytesSpilled","Update":0,"Value":0,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":9,"Name":"internal.metrics.diskBytesSpilled","Update":0,"Value":0,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":18,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.bytesWritten","Update":1627,"Value":10395,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":19,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.recordsWritten","Update":12,"Value":59,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":20,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.writeTime","Update":11705346,"Value":54412673,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true}]},"Task Metrics":{"Executor Deserialize Time":494,"Executor Deserialize CPU Time":51432980,"Executor Run Time":1022,"Executor CPU Time":133512654,"Result Size":2004,"JVM GC Time":95,"Result Serialization Time":0,"Memory Bytes Spilled":0,"Disk Bytes Spilled":0,"Shuffle Read Metrics":{"Remote Blocks Fetched":0,"Local Blocks Fetched":0,"Fetch Wait Time":0,"Remote Bytes Read":0,"Local Bytes Read":0,"Total Records Read":0},"Shuffle Write Metrics":{"Shuffle Bytes Written":1627,"Shuffle Write Time":11705346,"Shuffle Records Written":12},"Input Metrics":{"Bytes Read":0,"Records Read":0},"Output Metrics":{"Bytes Written":0,"Records Written":0},"Updated Blocks":[]}}`

Looks like I am able to get the Shuffle performance metrics in above event:

```
{"ID":18,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.bytesWritten","Update":2086,"Value":12481,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":19,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.recordsWritten","Update":12,"Value":71,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true},{"ID":20,"Name":"internal.metrics.shuffle.write.writeTime","Update":7177291,"Value":61589964,"Internal":true,"Count Failed Values":true}]}
```

How do I get the numbers I need above?

Comment: have you tried to look in [Spark UI](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-webui.html) for these metrics?

Comment: Hi @VladislavVarslavans I'm running the cluster on HDI in Azure and using Ambari UI. I see some application metrics there like Aggregate resource allocation and time elapsed.

Comment: never mind I found out how I get to the spark UI. There is good amount of data there I can scrape probably by webcrawler.

Comment: Exactly as I've told you :)

Comment: @VladislavVarslavans much appreciated :)